# Instalación Laravel Host/servidor

Tags: laravel, servidor, host

El caso es que he contratado un servidor, tiene CPanel pero no tiene acceso mediante SSH y por tanto no puedo hacer migraciones (lo contraté pensanso que sí tendría). Por otro lado, he contratado hosting que sí dispone de conexión SSH en Ionos. Pero de ninguna forma logro hacer que la app funcione en el dominio contratado.

Los pasos que estoy haciendo son los siguientes:

- Subo la aplicación en mi caso llamada 'lar' a la raiz del directorio del host/servidor.
- Paso el Public de mi app a la carpeta raiz del host/servidor Public_html
- Modifico las rutas del index.php:

```
require __DIR__.'/../lar/vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../lar/bootstrap/app.php';
$kernel = $app->make(Kernel::class);

$response = tap($kernel->handle(
    $request = Request::capture()
))->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

- Modifico AppServicePRovider y añado

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind('path.public', function (){
        return base_path().'/public_html';
    });
}
```

- En el archivo .env
  Dispongo de los datos que pienso están correctos:

```
APP_NAME=Prueba10 
APP_ENV=production 
APP_KEY=base64: 
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://nombre-del-dominio-contratado
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Este es el error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required
> '/homepages/42/d854271995/htdocs/public_html/../u113243151/lar/vendor/autoload.php'
> (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php8.0') in
> /homepages/42/d457576355/htdocs/public_html/index.php:34 Stack trace:
> #0 {main} thrown in /homepages/42/d457576355/htdocs/public_html/index.php on line 34

Comment: pueden ser los permisos que tiene la carpeta, verifica que tenga permisos, asimismo verifica que versión de php requieres para el proyecto que estar subiendo

Comment: @tecnobyte public_html tiene permisos 750 y lar (la de la app) dispone de 755, y la versión asignada al dominio es la 7.4 (estoy empleando Laravel 8.16.1)

Comment: de casualidad ejecutastes composer install?

Comment: @tecnobyte no puedo, no tengo acceso SSH

Comment: ese es el problema, laravel necesita la carpeta vendor y ese se crea ejecutando composer install, puedes descargarlo localmente y subirlo a tu servidor

Comment: ¿Tienes alguna referencia o guía localizada que me puedas pasar enlace?

Comment: @tecnobyte te estaría eternamente agradecido porque he probado de todo

Comment: puedes seguir esta guia para subir proyectos de laravel con cpanel https://soporte.dongee.com/es/articles/3299207-desplegar-laravel-en-cpanel

Comment: enfrente el mismo problema y lo solución fue subir los archivos de composer mediante ftp, se demora un poco más pero te sirve de esa forma

Comment: No había problema aparente. subí todo al public_html corrigiendo rutas y tampoco tiraba. La solución fue pedir al proveedor que reseteara el hosting, y listo. Todo correcto y funcionando.